# MVC, Model and Data Access Objects

Tags: php, oop, persistence

I have a theoretical question which I'm hoping someone can help me figure out.

I'm currently writing a simple web application in PHP using the MVC design pattern. I've seen and read a few tutorials on the subject, but they generally are either too complicated or overly simplified.

So what I have at the moment is a simple `User` model:

```
class User {

    private $username;
    private $group; //user, admin, etc

    // getters
}
```

I also have a simple `Database` class which implements this class:

```
interface DatabaseInterface {

    public function connect();
    public function disconnect();
    public function prepare($sql = null);
    public function execute($params = array());
    public function rowCount();
    public function fetch();
}
```

**My question is how should I link this `Database` class with populating my `User` class?**

What I have at the moment is another class called `UserDAO` which is passed a reference of the `Database` class in it's constructor, and it has a function called `ValidateUser()` which then uses the interface methods above to check the user against the database.

```
class UserDAO {

    private $database;

    public function __construct($database) {

        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function validateUser($username, $password) {

        $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE...');
        ....
        return true/false;
    }
}
```

And now I pass a `UserDAO` object into the `User` class through the constructor, and also add another `ValidateUser()` method into the `User` class, which basically just calls the `ValidateUser()` method within the `UserDAO` class.

The new `User` class:

```
class User {

    private $username;
    private $group; //user, admin, etc
    private $userDAO;

    public function __construct($userDAO) {

        $this->userDAO = $userDAO;
    }

    public function validateUser($username, $password) {

        if($this->userDAO->validateUser($username, $password)) {

            // set stuff that i need
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // getters
}
```

Something about this doesn't feel right to me. Would anyone be able help me understand the way this process normally flows?

Also, is the `Database` class normally kept static so I can just call for a connection using something like `Database::instance()`? Right now I'm creating one database object at the start of the PHP page and passing that around.

Feel free to leave me a comment if anything is unclear and I will try and fix it up ASAP.

Thanks for looking and sorry about the length of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how up-to-date your solution shall be.

### Singleton

The "oldest" Version is to have a static connection called everywhere. You realize this by using a **singleton**:

```
class database {

    private $instance = NULL;

    private function __construct()

    public function getDb() {
        return $this->instance?: $this->instance = new database();
    }

}
```

### Registry

A second, newer solution is to use a **registry**:
You could have a base class that is extended by all other classes, and that provides methods for a call like

```
$this->getRegistry()->getDb
```

Usually, the registry is filled at the beginning of your script, e.g. in the bootstrap.
Advantages are that you can better unittest the components since there are no static parts, and you can define different registries for dev and production environments...

### Dependency Injection

The third, "newest" and best method in **dependency injection**.
Usually you will have some framework that does this for you. The idea is that whenever you call a constuctor of a class, all dependencies like db connections are injected by the framework.

That way you can easily define "User needs DB and Redis. Shop needs DB, Config, and FTP"...
While this is an overhead for smaller projects, it in great help for huge and fully tested ones.

DI is well suited if you once upgrade to multiple DBs (e.g. one **master and multiple slaves**), as you can give every part of your code the DB it needs to get it´s job done, without changing a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks Zsolt. I haven't heard of Dependency Injection before but a quick Google reveals that I've used similar things before (kind of like how I'm injecting my UserDAO into my User class). I need to do a bit more research on it first though to figure out how I should set it up.

Answer (score 1):

When passing the database connection into your UserDOA object you're creating a dependency. Your UserDOA object is now dependent on the database instance.

Without a doubt the best way to manage these dependencies (not just with your UserDOA but your other DOA classes and more) is via an **IoC** (Inversion of Control) container using **Dependency Injection**.

Dependency injection allows you to register components/classes (and arguments required to create an object instance of the class) within a container, and then have the (in your case) database instance injected into it whatever class you specify. This makes code far more manageable, extensible, loosely coupled and follows the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

One dependency injection container I would recommend taking a look at is [Symfony's dependency injection component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) which has been extracted and can be used on its own.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, for a business project, to do a anemic model is practically the only way to go.

So, instead of creating a bloated model (or domain object) with several member/operator/functions, we have a single model with only the definition of the field and we have separated classes with the services.

a) model classes should be easy and it should changes if the model of the project changes (for example, if we add a new field to the table of the database).  Usually a model is an entity (a mirror of a table)

b) the dao class (one of the service) does the crud.  As a service, it could be static (if not, it should be), so calling it should be easiest:

```
public function validateUser($username, $password) {

    if(UserDAO::validateUser($username, $password)) {

        // set stuff that i need
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

However, for this specific case, the function validateUser is more related with the LOGIC (a class that could changes if the business conditions changes).  So we could creates a new class of service that does the validation

```
class UserLogic {
    public static validateUser($user) {
        $userInDb=UserDao::getUser($user->idUser);
        // here goes the logic
        // why?, because it could changes, for example, validating the date, attempts, if its active...
        if ($userInDb!=null && $userInDb->password=$user->password) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And for calling this function we used :

```
  $isValid=UserLogic::validateUser($someUser);
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into singletons, such as $this->db = DB::getInstance();

Example:

```
class Database { 
    // Store the single instance of Database 
    private static $instance; 

    private function __construct() { 
      // connection here
    } 

    public static function getInstance() { 
        if (!self::$instance) { 
            self::$instance = new Database(); 
        } 

        return self::$instance; 
    } 
}  

$db = new Database(); // the old way, don't do this.
$db = Database::getInstance(); // the singleton way - do this everywhere! it will always return the same object
```